# Segmentation fault when trying to modify a string

Tags: c

This code is giving me a segmentation fault at run time.

```
char *str = "HELLO";
str[0] = str[2];
```

Please can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Who is upvoting this ? Not a bad question but stackexchange will reach the point where it will detect this question and be able to point users at the c-faq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard does not allow modifying a string literal. The string is stored in a readonly segment of the program, for example in linux, it is stored in the `.rodata` section of the executable which cannot be written.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot modify the contents of a string literal.  Put it in a character array if you wish to be able to do so.

```
char str[] = "HELLO";
str[0] = str[2];
```

Answer (score 7):

You're getting a seg-fault because the compiler has placed the string constant "HELLO" into read-only memory - and attempting to modify the string is thus failing.

Answer (score 4):

This is compiled to a string literal in the read only section.

```
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "HELLO"
```